# .htaccess 301 redirect not redirecting to the French urls properly

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I am using a 301 redirect command in .htaccess file

```
Redirect 301 /fr/emergency http://www.sitename.com/fr/d’urgence
```

But on redirection the url has turned out to be http://www.sitename.com/fr/d%92urgence and shows a page not found error.

The requirement is that it needs to come as [http://www.sitename.com/fr/d’urgence](http://www.sitename.com/fr/d%E2%80%99urgence) itself.

Any idea what needs to be corrected and where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string should be encoded in UTF-8 and then percent encoded.  You should never use non-ASCII characters in a URL sent over the wire (at least, not yet... someday), and this is the way around it.

```
Redirect 301 /fr/emergency http://www.sitename.com/fr/d%E2%80%99urgence
```

A web browser will still display it as `d’urgence`, the user will never see the percent-encoded version.  This assumes that the `’` character is actually supposed to be U+2019 "right single quotation mark" and not U+0027 "apostrophe".

Comment: This is fine and it worked for the web browser. But when the search engine caches this page will it caches as fr/d%E2%80%99urgence or fr/d’urgence?

Comment: They are both the same.  `fr/d%E2%80%99urgence` is what gets sent over the wire, `fr/d’urgence` is what gets displayed to the user.